# Python threading only launching one extra thread

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import socket
import thread
s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("server", 6661))
def recv():
    while 1:
        print(s.recv(1024))
def send():
    while 1:
        msg = raw_input("> ")
        s.send(msg)
thread.start_new_thread(recv())
thread.start_new_thread(send())
```

Why does the code not run after thread recv() - I can't see where it should hang

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust as follow:

```
thread.start_new_thread(recv, ())
thread.start_new_thread(send, ())
```

By appending `()` right after the function name, you call `recv` and `send` in main thread, not in new thread.

Comment: I did try that, but then I get this error:

TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: @AndrewBerry, I forgot about the `args` parameter. I updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: is there any way I can get the recv thread to print as soon as it receives?

At the moment it's only printing after I press enter on the send thread...

Comment: @AndrewBerry, Without knowing what the `server` does, I can't answer that. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewBerry, I don't understand what you mean. See http://asciinema.org/a/6154 .

Comment: This is strange, when you ran it,  that's the behavior I am going for, but not what's happening on my client.

it just doesn't print the received message until after the client sends one, thank you for your help though :)